# GWT Presenter class error

Tags: java

I am having Set inside DTO and i want to get all the values of that set in my Presenter class in GWT, how to get it

```java
public List<MenuDTO> getMenuDetails() {
        List<MenuDTO> menu = new ArrayList<MenuDTO>();
        MenuDTO menuValue = new MenuDTO();
        SubMenuDTO subMenuValue = new SubMenuDTO();
        SubMenuDTO subMenuValue1 = new SubMenuDTO();
        menuValue.setMenuHeading("Home");
        Set<SubMenuDTO> setvalue = new HashSet<SubMenuDTO>();
        subMenuValue.setMenuHeading("file");
        subMenuValue1.setMenuHeading("Copy");
        setvalue.add(subMenuValue);
        setvalue.add(subMenuValue1);
        menuValue.setSubMenuItems(setvalue);
        menu.add(menuValue);
        return menu;
    }
```

output:-

```
[com.dupont.rsms.commons.dto.SubMenuDTO@2dafd034, com.dupont.rsms.commons.dto.SubMenuDTO@718e1d5a]
```

i am not able to convert to string please help me in regarding this.

Comment: Please consider a different title for your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing the values of the SubMenuDTO objects, but they do not implement a `toString()` method, so the default `Object.toString()` method is being used instead. That is why the output looks as it does.

Consider writing a `toString()` method or finding another way to retrieve the value you wish to print.

Comment: Thank you. i have realized my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Generally if you are printing an object, it's `toString()` method will be called. If you don't  override this method, it's superclass' `toString()` method will be called(In most cases, it is of Object class' `toString()` method). If you look at the implementation of Object class' toString() method, it will look like `getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())`. That's why you are getting output like this.